# Write raster using nc data in r

Tags: r, rstudio, gis, noaa

I am using https://ldas.gsfc.nasa.gov/gldas GLDAS_NOAH10_M: GLDAS Noah Land Surface Model (netcdf4 format) to extract snow water equivalent and soil moisture.

Snow water equivalent shows 3 dimensions(lat, lon and time) and I can easily write its raster (tiff format) as shown in photo and code.

Soil Moisture contains 4 dimensions (lat, lon, depth, time) which is harder to export. Can any one know how to write raster in tiff format in that situation ? Thanks.

Libraries :

```
library(raster)
library(sp)
library(rgdal)
library(ncdf4)
library(tiff)
```

Path :

```
ncpath <- "D:\\GLDAS Data\\2002_GLDAS\\"
ncname <- "GLDAS_NOAH10_M.A200201.001.grb.SUB"
```

**Case 1**

```
ncfname <- paste(ncpath, ncname, ".nc4", sep="")
ncin <- nc_open(ncfname)
```

Check :
    print(ncin)

Variables :

```
lon <- ncvar_get(ncin, "lon")
lat <- ncvar_get(ncin, "lat")
b_unit <- ncatt_get(ncin,"SWE","units")
swe.array <- ncvar_get(ncin, "SWE")
dim(swe.array)
fillvalue <- ncatt_get(ncin, "SWE", "_FillValue")
nc_close(ncin)
```

Export :

```
b <- raster(swe.array, xmn=min(lon), xmx=max(lon), ymn=min(lat), ymx=max(lat), crs=CRS("+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs+ towgs84=0,0,0"))
b <- flip (b, direction = 'y')
writeRaster(b, file = paste0("D:\\GLDAS Data\\2002_GLDAS\\SWE_mm_month_200201",".tif"), overwrite = TRUE)
```

**Case 2**

```
ncfname <- paste(ncpath, ncname, ".nc4", sep="")
ncin <- nc_open(ncfname)
print(ncin)
lon <- ncvar_get(ncin, "lon")
lat <- ncvar_get(ncin, "lat")
c_unit <- ncatt_get(ncin,"SoilMoist","units")
sm.array <- ncvar_get(ncin, "SoilMoist")
dim(sm.array)
fillvalue <- ncatt_get(ncin, "SoilMoist", "_FillValue")
nc_close(ncin)
```

Export :

```
c <- raster(sm.array, xmn=min(lon), xmx=max(lon), ymn=min(lat), ymx=max(lat), 
            crs=CRS("+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs+ towgs84=0,0,0"))
c <- flip (c, direction = 'y')
writeRaster(c, file = paste0("D:\\GLDAS Data\\2002_GLDAS\\SM_mm_month_200201",".tif"),overwrite = TRUE)
```

[image: photo of code]

Comment: Could you provide a minimal example or a data set which gives us the possibility to improve your code and answer your question ? Moreover it seems that ncname doesn't between two cases is it normal ? If yes, it isn't necessary to add both time the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly read nc-files as raster objects using raster(). To extract data for a level in your 4D-data for soil moisture, you can extract single levels by specifying them using the level argument.

```
c <- raster(ncfname, level = 1)
writeRaster(c, file = paste0("D:\\GLDAS Data\\2002_GLDAS\\SM_mm_month_200201",".tif"),overwrite = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thank you for your kind support. Can you please help me a little bit more here.   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59322563/how-to-subtract-3-rasters-from-1-raster-with-different-extents-and-resolutions