# How to subtract 3 rasters from 1 raster with different extents and resolutions

Tags: r, rstudio

I have 4 rasters with different resolutions and extents. Can anyone help me how to subtract 3 rasters (a,b,c) from raster (d1) to get the new output raster named as "e"

like   e= d1-a-b-c.
`

```
d1
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 180, 360, 64800  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 1, 1  (x, y)
extent     : -1.110223e-16, 360, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
source     : memory
names      : Liquid_Water_Equivalent_Thickness 
values     : -249.2061, 806.3248  (min, max)

> a
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 39, 46, 1794  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 0.826087, 1.153846  (x, y)
extent     : 48, 86, 6, 51  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
source     : memory
names      : layer 
values     : 0, 0.4987984  (min, max)

> b
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 39, 46, 1794  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 0.826087, 1.153846  (x, y)
extent     : 48, 86, 6, 51  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
source     : memory
names      : layer 
values     : 0, 555.5283  (min, max)

> c
class      : RasterLayer 
band       : 1  (of  4  bands)
dimensions : 46, 39, 1794  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 1, 1  (x, y)
extent     : 47.5, 86.5, 5.5, 51.5  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
source     : D:/GLDAS Data/2002_GLDAS/GLDAS_NOAH10_M.A200201.001.grb.SUB.nc4 
names      : Average.layer.1.soil.moisture 
z-value    : 2 
zvar       : SoilMoist 
level      : 1
```

`

Answer (score 1):

To make this possible, you need to make sure the extents and the resolutions of every rasters are the same, here is my code below, which makes sample rasters and works through them to make them have the same extent and resolution. Here is the code with comments:

```
#### ----- Making Sample rasters ----- ####
e1 <- extent(-1.110223e-16, 360, -90, 90)
d1 <- raster(e1)
res(d1) <- 1
d1[] <- runif(64800, min = 0, max = 1)
#plot(d1)

e2 <- extent(48, 86, 6, 51)
a <- raster(e2)
res(a) <- c(0.826087, 1.153846)
a[] <- rnorm(1794, 5, 1)
#plot(a)

e3 <- extent(48, 86, 6, 51)
b <- raster(e3)
res(b) <- c(0.826087, 1.153846)
b[] <- rnorm(1794, 12, 1)

e3 <- extent(47.5, 86.5, 5.5, 51.5)
c <- raster(e3)
res(c) <- 1
c[] <- rnorm(1794, 12, 1)

crs(d1) = crs("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0")
crs(a) = crs("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0")
crs(b) = crs("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0")
crs(c) = crs("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0")
#### ----- Making Sample rasters ----- ####


##### Cropping all rasters to the lowest extent #####
ex <- intersect(intersect(intersect(extent(a), extent(b)), extent(c)), extent(d1))

d1_crop = crop(d1, ex)
a_crop = crop(a, ex)
b_crop = crop(b, ex)
c_crop = crop(c, ex)
##### Cropping all rasters to the lowest extent #####


##### Reprojecting the rasters to make them the same resolution, making them the same as d1's resolution #####
a_res = projectRaster(a_crop, d1_crop)
b_res = projectRaster(b_crop, d1_crop)
c_res = projectRaster(c_crop, d1_crop)
##### Reprojecting the rasters to make them the same resolution, making them the same as d1's resolution #####

##### Doing your calculations after the resolution and extents are the same.
e = d1_crop-a_res-b_res-c_res
```